# cannot create an instance using UserStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-identity

I just defined an instance using UserStore as follows.

```
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ProjectEntities());
```

but getting following error

> The type 'project_name.Models.ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserStore'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'project_name.Models.ApplicationUser' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser'.

here how I defined `ApplicationUser` in `IdentityModel.cs`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
    this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    // custom User properties/code here
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the bug is very clear in what you doing wrong

you are trying to pass `ApplicationUser`, but `UserStore` requires you to use the type that of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUse` you should probably extend/inherit ApplicationUser from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUse`

something like

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
```

Comment: `ApplicationUser` in `IdentityModels.cs` file existing as like this `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string,ApplicationUserLogin,ApplicationUserRole,ApplicationUserClaim>
    {`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using `IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>` instead of `IdentityUser` as COLD TOLD points out since the most common use of that signature is to use INT keys instead of string. Use IdentityUser and you will get string keys by default.

So, assuming you have another reason for going with that signature, you will need to override the entire identity stack: IdentityUser, IdentityUserRole, IdentityRole, IdentityUserClaim, IdentityUserLogin,  IdentityDbContext, UserStore and RoleStore.

So UserStore would be:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : 
    UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
    ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, 
    ApplicationUserClaim>, IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, 
    IDisposable
{
    public ApplicationUserStore() : this(new IdentityDbContext())
    {
        base.DisposeContext = true;
    }

    public ApplicationUserStore(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

See http://johnatten.com/2014/07/13/asp-net-identity-2-0-extending-identity-models-and-using-integer-keys-instead-of-strings/

Comment: In my `IdentityModels.cs` file I have `ApplicationUserStore` [as follows](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/xrnE8) but once I replace that with your code snippet getting 6 compile time errors, first is like this `The type 'project_name.Models.ApplicationUserRole' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUserRole' in the generic type or method 'UserStore<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>'.`

Comment: You have to override all 8 identity classes (or use the non-generic IdentityUser).